# django field is required validators

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

i have some forms at one page and I try to validate some fields too.

So if I enter wrong input at the test field, I get obviously the message ' invalid input', but also for each other field the messages 'This field is required.'.

How could I fix it? Override the clean function? But how?

```
class Example1Form(forms.ModelForm):

    test = forms.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$'), MaxLengthValidator(30)])
```

And I also distinguish the different forms like:

```
class View(TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_example1 = Example1Form(request.POST)
        form_example2 = Example2Form(request.POST)
        if form_example1.is_valid():
             ....
             form_example2 = Example2Form()
             return render(request, self.template, {'form_example1': form_example1, 'form_example2': form_example2})

        if form_example2.is_valid():
            ....
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: What you want to fix?

Comment: I don't want get the messages for other forms. I have many forms with many submit buttons. But I get also 'is required' messages for different form.

Comment: Then in view you should check which form was submitted and only perform `is_valid` on submitted form not on other forms.

Comment: I have this. I extend some code more.

Comment: `.is_valid()` not `.is_valid` - its a function, not a property. `.is_valid` will always be "true".

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I use of course the ``is_valid()`` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a way to tell which form was submitted. You could name your submit buttons, for example:

```
<form>
    {{ form_example1 }}
    <input name="form_example_1" type="submit" value="Submit form 1">
</form>

<form>
    {{ form_example2 }}
    <input name="form_example_2" type="submit" value="Submit form 2">
</form>
```

Then, in your view, you should only bind your form to the POST data if that form was submitted. For example:

```
if "form_example1" in request.POST:
    form_example1 = Example1Form(request.POST)
else:
    form_example1 = Example1Form()

if "form_example2" in request.POST:
    form_example2 = Example2Form(request.POST)
else:
    form_example2 = Example2Form()
```